# Timepicker not working on rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So, If you've used date picker then you'll know how it works - when you click on the field that date picker is associated with a calendar box will pop up with jquery and allow the user to choose a date.

Basically, this isn't happening with my time picker, time field. It just acts as a text_field and no time picker box pops up for a user to choose a time. Datepicker works perfectly fine, but I'm not sure why Timepicker isn't as I've never used it before.

I've downloaded the library, and required it in the .js and .css files, what am I doing wrong?

event.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  if $('#event_date').length > 0
    $('#event_date').datepicker <---datepicker which works 
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' 

$('#event_time').timepicker({ 'scrollDefaultNow': true }); <--- time picker which doesn't work
```

form.html.rb

```
File Edit Options Tools Rinari nXhtml Buffers Services Help                                                                                                   
<%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>                                                                                                                          
  <h5>Event title:</h5>                                                                                                                                       
  <div><%= f.input_field :title, placeholder: "Event title", required: true, autocomplete: :off %></div>                                                      
  <h5>Event description:</h5>                                                                                                                                 
  <div><%= f.input_field :description, placeholder: "Event description", required: true, autocomplete: :off %></div>                                          
  <h5>Event date:</h5>                                                                                                                                        
  <div><%= f.text_field :date  %></div> <---datepicker which works                                                                                                                       
  <div><%= f.text_field :time, id: "event_time" %></div> <--- time picker which doesn't work                                                                                                     
  <h5>Event location:</h5>                                                                                                                                    
  <div><%= f.input_field :location, placeholder: "Event location", required: true, autocomplete: :off %></div>                                                
  <div><%= f.submit @event.new_record? ? "Create event" : "Update event"  %></div><br />                                                                      
<% end %>
```

Comment: any error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put:

```
$('#event_time').timepicker({ 'scrollDefaultNow': true });
```

Inside jQuery's document ready function like you do with the first time picker Like this:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#event_time').timepicker({ 'scrollDefaultNow': true });
```

Any `$()` methods that reference a dom element need to be in this `jQuery ->` function so that the dom is ready and available for `$()` to find elements and act upon them. Unless, you load your script at the bottom of your page just above `</body>`.

Also you don't need to check:

```
if $('#event_date').length > 0
```

because calling

```
$('#event_date').datepicker
```

will not do anything if it doesn't find an `#event_date`.